# Check entered information in Column A with Column C. If it matches information in Column C then show information in the row next to that row

Tags: excel, formula, matching

I am trying to create a inventory list that would automatically check entered information (Column A) within another column (Column E). If it matches then it will display information status from Row next to the matching column (Column F) into (Column B)

Please see image below. The user will only be entering information in COLUMN A and COLUMN C

Image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDhAe.jpg

Comment: The function you need is called VLOOKUP.

Comment: I tried doing IFERROR formula I am not familiar with VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

combining VLOOKUP with ISERROR

First construct your VLOOKUP statement

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE)
```

Once you are happy that it is giving `#N/A!` and appopriate values in the correct place, we can wrap it in an IFERROR

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE),"NO MATCH")
```

The reason we wait to put the IFERROR in place is that it hides all errors, so if you've mistyped something, it's going to get hidden if we put it in at the start.